# python pydantic how to mark field as secret

Tags: python, security, pydantic

How to mark pydantic model filed as secret so it will not shown in the **repr** **str** and will be excluded from dict and etc...

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    password_hash: str  # I do not want this field to leak out.
```

I write my code with security in mind and I afraid that in the future someone else will write non secure code that will leak the 'password_hash' field outside to the logs etc...

Is there a way to mark the field as secret to be sure it not leak out?

Comment: Er, isn't this the entire purpose of [SecretStr](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#secret-types)? `name: SecretStr`, `password_hash: SecretStr`...?

Comment: I did not know about it. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pydantic provides convenience [`Secret*` classes](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#secret-types) for this exact purpose:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, SecretStr

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    password_hash: SecretStr
```